# Как называется контейнер хранящий N лучших элементов?

Tags: массивы, структуры, терминология, любой-язык

У меня есть контейнер фиксированного размера содержащий упорядоченные элементы. В конструкторе я передаю в него его максимальный размер и функцию сравнения. При добавлении элемента, контейнер использует функцию сравнения и добавляет новый элемент к другим элементам так, чтобы сохранить порядок от лучшего к худшему и, если достигнут предел, выбрасывает худший элемент.

Есть ли у такого контейнера каноническое название (английский и русский термины) ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

На мой взгляд, канонического названия у такой структуры нет. В зависимости от задачи она может иметь разные названия. Как примеры:

- [LRU Cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_algorithms): в данной структуре данные упорядочиваются по частоте обращений к ним, наименее используемые удаляются при достижении заданного размера кэша.
- MRU Cache: такой же принцип, но в отличии от LRU вытесняется последний использованный элемент.
- [EvictingQueue](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/EvictingQueue.html): структура данных из Guava, первый элемент очереди удаляется, если очередь заполнена. Также есть [MinMaxPriorityQueue](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/MinMaxPriorityQueue.html).
- [CircularFifoQueue](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections4/queue/CircularFifoQueue.html): структура данных из Apache Commons, заменяет старейший элемент, если очередь заполнена.

Думаю, в зависимости от семантики структуры данных и принципа ее реализации (на основе очереди, хэш-таблицы или еще какой-либо лежащий в основе структуры) название может варьироваться.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала, я бы не стал называть такую структуру данных контейнером. От контейнера ожидается, что он будет хранить все элементы а не только те, которые ему понадобятся.

По поводу же названия - встречается такая структура нечасто (по причине, изложенной выше), и общеизвестного названия у нее нет. Я бы назвал ее "буфер лучших элементов".

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что если вставка подразумевает замещение одного из старых элементов это уже не контейнер? А если добавления вообще нет, а только замещение (например std::array) это тоже не контейнер?

Comment: @alexolut если добавления вообще нет - это нормальный контейнер. Потому что он удовлетворяет условию "добавленные элементы сами собой никуда не пропадают".

Comment: Так вытеснение из-за добавления нового это, имхо, не "само собой".

Answer (score 0):

В `C++` такого рода контейнер называется "очередь с приоритетом" [`std::priority_queue`](http://ru.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue). Правда, автоматического вытеснения, о котором упомянуто вопросе, при достижении максимального размера не происходит. Такую функциональность можно достаточно легко реализовать самостоятельно.
Итоговый вариант можно было бы назвать "Очередь фиксированного размера с приоритетом" (`fixed_size_priority_queue`).

Comment: Скажу больше, все уже реализовано, дело только за названием :-)

Comment: @KromStern, imho priority_queue реализована через heap (пирамида). М.б. и у Вас также?

Answer (score -1):

Может быть [Circular buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer) (кольцевой буфер)

Comment: С кольцевым буфером совпадает только то что он имеет фиксированный размер. По дефолту, у него нет сортировки при вставке. Также в моем случае закольцованность никак не востребована и только усложнила бы контейнер.

Answer (score -1):

Я бы использовал обычный `multi_set`.

Как-то так:

```cpp
multi_set <int> best;

if (best.size() < lim || x > *best.begin())
{
  best.insert(x);
  if (best.size() > lim)
    best.erase(best.begin());
}
```

Comment: Вопрос о названии, а не о возможной реализации.

Comment: Перечитайте вопрос пожалуйста. Он не о том как это сделать (все уже сделано и отлично работает), а в том как такая структура-контейнер называется (если у нее есть каноническое название).

Comment: @KromStern, что-то я сомневаюсь, что у неё есть название. Нельзя же под каждую частную задачу придумывать уникальное общепринятое название.

Comment: Тогда у вас 2 варианта, либо написать ответ что названия нет, либо, как и я, надеяться что оно есть и станет известно.